# What's a use case where I would _not_ want to automatically git prune?

Tags: git

Git supports the option to prune on every fetch (`fetch.prune`). What is a good example use case where I would *not* want to prune my refs to non-existent upstream branches?

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm generally considered a Git guru and I set `fetch.prune` to `true`. That doesn't mean such use cases don't exist, but they seem pretty rare.

Comment: Oooh. Perhaps this: unmerged branch `foo` exists on origin. `foo` is the only ref to this chain of commits. Someone deletes this branch (on origin). If everyone does `git fetch --prune`, then all local trees will have removed their (only) reference to the commit chain, and thus the branch is now subject to garbage collection everywhere, and thus potentially lost forever. Legit? Given this, it seems there should be a prune-only-merged-commit-referencing-but-deleted-refs.

Comment: Sure—but if someone deleted `foo` everywhere else, and you have not started using it yourself, that's strong evidence that you never cared about those commits in the first place. (I have seen people accidentally delete branches they did not mean to delete, but a better way to recover from such things is to have proper backups on the server, e.g., to use ZFS with frequent snapshots.)

Comment: @torek — you're thinking of catastrophic data deletion. I'm thinking version control and history of development state, including abandoned or parked lines of development (unused ≠ unimportant). If I realize a year later that I'd like to review an abandoned solution, but it's been pruned from history, then I'm forced to grovel through backups as a poor version control (Backup ≠ VCS). Backups are also of no use when you've erased history of what once existed there (you may not even know that there's data that you now care about).